# Angular 2 animating currently hovered element only

Tags: angular

Here's the HTML:

```
    <div *ngFor="let project of projects" (mouseenter)='toggleFocus()'>
            <div class="project-info"  [@infoSlide]='state'>
                <p>My project title here</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Because this is an `*ngFor`, multiple div's of class `project-info` contain the trigger `infoSlide`. This means that when I hover over a specific div, *all* `project-info` divs animate in, aside from the current hover target element.

How can I make it so that only the currently hovered element animates?

I know I can use CSS, but I would prefer to stick with Angular 2 animations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a #currentDiv local variable. Pass the #currentDiv to your toggleFocus method and you could add class or add specific CSS to the div you just hovered.

```
<div *ngFor="let project of projects" #currentDiv (mouseenter)='toggleFocus(currentDiv)'>
        <div class="project-info"[@infoSlide]='state'>
            <p>My project title here</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: But still, in this case, I wouldn't be able to use actual Angular 2 Animations with triggers right?  I would just be able to attach CSS-based animations?